# My loop in Puppeteer isn't looping when creating PDF files from webpages

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer, headless-browser

I'm attempting to use Puppeteer to scrape about 300 webpages to PDF, but my loop isn't working. The intent is that Puppeteer loads each page from an array, generates a PDF, and then works through all of the URLs before closing.

Using the code below, Puppeteer successfully scrapes the first URL -- and then stops.

Code (URLs are placeholders):

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  // Create a browser instance
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: true });

  // Create a new page
  const page = await browser.newPage();

  // Set viewport width and height
  await page.setViewport({ width: 1280, height: 720 });

  const urlArray = [
    'https://ask.metafilter.com/369890/Patio-furniture-designed-for-the-PNW',
    'https://ask.metafilter.com/369889/Its-the-police-should-I-document-my-concern',
    'https://ask.metafilter.com/369888/Training-my-over-excited-dog'
  ];

for(var i = 0; i < urlArray.length; i++) {

  const website_url = urlArray[i];

  // Open URL in current page
  await page.goto(website_url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle0' });

  // Download the PDF
  const pdf = await page.pdf({
    path: 'images/page_${i+1}.pdf',
    margin: { top: '100px', right: '50px', bottom: '100px', left: '50px' },
    printBackground: true,
  });


}
  // Close the browser instance
  await browser.close();
})();
```

However, if I attempt to create a screenshot, swapping out this:

```
// Download the PDF
  const pdf = await page.pdf({
    path: 'images/page.pdf',
    margin: { top: '100px', right: '50px', bottom: '100px', left: '50px' },
    printBackground: true,
  });
```

For this:

```
// Capture screenshot
  await page.screenshot({
    path: `images/screenshot_full_${i+1}.jpg`,
    fullPage: true
  });
```

It loops fine, and goes through every URL in the array.

What am I missing?

I'm working from these tutorials:
https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-make-a-pdf-from-html-with-node-js-and-puppeteer/, https://www.bannerbear.com/blog/how-to-take-screenshots-with-puppeteer/

Comment: `'images/page_${i+1}.pdf'` shouldn't that be backticks for a template literal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @ggorlen pointed out, I was using single quotation marks where I should have had backticks:

```
path: 'images/page_${i+1}.pdf'
```

Should be:

```
path: `images/page_${i+1}.pdf`
```